file permissions: give write permissions to system
I looked around online and was unable to clarify this.
When I use chmod to change file permissions for a file to look something like this: -rw-rw-r I know that #1 is the owner #2 is for group permissions and #3 is for others.
With that in mind is the last one #3 (others) include the systems permissions? In other words if I did chmod w+x then would the outcome be the system can write and execute a file?

"Other" means anybody not that is not the user or in the named group. So if anybody can execute a script by allowing o+x then the "system" can execute the script as well. But "system" might be a bit vague, or is system the specific user? System might be root or www-data, depending on the service.

Seems like you change your question a bit, so I'll have to correct you there about the w+x. The correct syntax would be either chmod o+rx <filename> or chmod 665 <filename>. Be aware that if you use o+rx you'll add these permissions for others. So if there is a w permission for other already, you'll have to remove it by chmod o-w <filename>

Also, "the system" is an invalid idea. There are multiple userids used in running Ubuntu. All but 1 of them gets "other" access. The exception is the root user (UID=0). root is used to manage the system, and has unconstrained access. The root does NOT login. Rather, on modern Linux systems, sudo is used. Explore your Mount/Read/Write/Execute problems with https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld, a bash script to show the permissions, mount options along the path to an object or objects.

chmod w+x is an erroneous command. It should read chmod +w+x or chmod +wx.
In this invocation of the chmod command, you change the file mode, but you do not specify which users are affected. So defaults apply:

For r and w, by default only the user bit is changed.
For x, by default all users (user, group, others) are affected.

You can explicitly indicate for which users the file mode should be changed by preceding the mode (e.g. +x) with the target group (a: all, u: user, g: group, o: others). For example, chmod o-x <file> will turn off the executable bit for "others" only. These letters can also be combined as in chmod ug+wx. See man chmod for more detail.

The only "system permissions" on a standard, old-school UNIX-like system are the root user's access, and root can traditionally access anything.
Beyond that, any sort of idea of "system" permissions requires an extension like SELinux; traditional UNIX access levels did not recognize "system" accounts or processes other than ones running as root.
So, if you have a file that's owned by your user account and in your user group, but has no other permissions, then e.g. apache will have no access to that file (unless the apache user is a member of your user group). Nor will any account other than yours, and root.
SELinux changes all of this in complicated ways, for processes that aren't running unconfined, but with only the standard UNIX permissions that's how things work.
(Keep in mind, also, that whether an account can access a given file is also affected by the directory permissions of the directory that contains the file, and every parent directory up the chain.)

Where did SELinux come into play, since this is not used on Ubuntu?

@ArturMeinild It didn't. But it's an example of an access-control layer that would make the notion of "system permissions" (as raised in the question) a meaningful one, whereas in standard UNIX access control it isn't.
